# Magento get correct base url from AWS hosted Magento

Tags: magento, amazon-web-services

I have magento running on an AWS host.

Whenever I use Magento's built in "get base url" functions,  I get paths like, for example

```
 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/skin/frontend/base/default/css/widgets.css
```

but the "server root" (not sure of right word) is the /htdocs/ file.  I have a java file that accepts files,  but it is looking for files starting at the /htdocs/ folder.  When I send it a file like the above example,  it looks for /htdocs/opt/bitnami/apps/magento/...

Does anyone know how to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you will get the complete path and not starting from /htdocs..

A simple workaround may be to strip the characters before /htdocs,

```
$path = "/opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/skin/frontend/base/default/css/widgets.css";
echo strstr($path, "/htdocs");
```

will give you:

```
/htdocs/skin/frontend/base/default/css/widgets.css
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution.  I had implemented something similar on my own too.  Thanks!